# Getting repeated data - screenscraping using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping a website using the following code from the

`URL`: [99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?](http://99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?)

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
import MySQLdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

today = datetime.date.today()
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid").read()

soup = Soup(html)
print "INSERT INTO Property (URL,Rooms, Place, Phonenumber1,Phonenumber2,Phonenumber3,Typeofperson, Name)"
print "VALUES ("
re_digit = re.compile('(\d+)')
pdate = soup.findAll('i', {'class':'pdate'})
properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
for eachproperty in properties:
# title = today,","+"http:/"+ eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string+"," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])) 
    for eachdate in pdate:
        pdates = re.sub('(\s{2,})', ' ', eachdate.text)
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sT_disc grey'}):
        try:
            project = div.find('span').find('b').text.strip()
        except:
            project = 'No project'  
        area = re.findall(re_digit, div.find('i', {'class': 'blk'}).text.strip())

        print today,","+"http:/"+ eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string+"," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick']))+","+ ", ".join([project] + area),","+pdates
print ")"
```

If you run this you will see that the data is getting repeated. Other than that all the required datas are getting scraped. But I cannot figure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping unnecessarily. What you need to do is following:

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

today = datetime.date.today()
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid").read()

soup = Soup(html)
print "INSERT INTO Property (URL,Rooms, Place, Phonenumber1,Phonenumber2,Phonenumber3,Typeofperson, Name)"
print "VALUES ("
re_digit = re.compile('(\d+)')
properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))

for eachproperty in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'sT'}):
  a      = eachproperty.find('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
  pdate  = eachproperty.find('i', {'class':'pdate'})
  pdates = re.sub('(\s{2,})', ' ', pdate.text)
  div    = eachproperty.find('div', {'class': 'sT_disc grey'})
  try:
    project = div.find('span').find('b').text.strip()
  except:
    project = 'No project'        
  area = re.findall(re_digit, div.find('i', {'class': 'blk'}).text.strip())
  print today,","+"http:/"+ (a['href'] if a else '')+",", (a.string if a else '')+ "," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else '')))+","+ ", ".join([project] + area),","+pdates
```